# Everything is labeled, but some of the labels are misleading

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a line about a book in which the humanity can no longer understand things (due to some changes in their planet's structure or something) and now they have labels on everything, some of which are quite deceiving. One example is a very narrow and uneven street labeled "highway" and people believe it's a highway because of the label.

Note that this isn't Earth but another planet.

Comment: Can you remember any more details? Like when you read it (What year)? Where you might have seen it, any character names? If you do just [edit] then in. Don't forget to take our [tour] and earn your first badge!

Comment: Reminds me of this; https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RyGVAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT45&lpg=PT45&dq=%22She+must+be+milked+every+morning+so+that+she+will+produce+milk%22&source=bl&ots=SFpTbHr8rs&sig=4kta7rLhodflOdSTG_Mb2LWrtD8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKzeyWg-vUAhURalAKHdnPBToQ6AEISTAG#v=onepage&q=%22She%20must%20be%20milked%20every%20morning%20so%20that%20she%20will%20produce%20milk%22&f=false